# Menu procedure that can call data from file Python3

Tags: python, list, dictionary, menu

I've create a file that will create data to a file, print that file, and I am now trying to create a menu procedure which will allow the user to enter a particular colour, in which the file will then print out the data for that colour. My code is as follows:

```
def createFile(allColours):
    colours = open("colours","w")
    colours.write(str(allColours))
    colours.close()
    output()

def output():
    colours = open("colours","r")
    outputQuestion = input("Would you like the to see the output of the data for colours?(Y/N) \n")
    if outputQuestion == "Y" or outputQuestion == "y":
        for counter in range(4):
            print(colours.readline())
        colours.close()
    menu()




def data():
    allColours = []               
    allColours.append({"ID": "1", "Shade": "Black", "Red": "0", "Green": "0", "Blue":"0"})
    allColours.append ({"ID": "2", "Shade": "White", "Red": "255", "Green": "255", "Blue":"255"})
    allColours.append ({"ID": "3", "Shade": "Red", "Red": "255", "Green": "0", "Blue":"0"})
    allColours.append ({"ID": "4", "Shade": "Green", "Red": "0", "Green": "255", "Blue":"0"})
    allColours.append ({"ID": "5", "Shade": "Blue", "Red": "0", "Green": "0", "Blue":"255"})
    createFile(allColours)

def menu():
    colours = open("colours","r")
    whatColour = input("What colour would you like to be looked up?\n")
    if whatColour == "Black":
        print(colours[0])
```

As the def menu() show you, I want the program to ask the user what colour to be looked up. If the user says black, for example, the program should print the details for that dictionary.

I was also wondering if there was a way so that in def output(), each data entry would be split by a new line. At the moment, when I print it, it comes out as a long list as follows:

```
[{'ID': '1', 'Shade': 'Black', 'Red': '0', 'Green': '0', 'Blue': '0'}, {'ID': '2', 'Shade': 'White', 'Red': '255', 'Green': '255', 'Blue': '255'}, {'ID': '3', 'Shade': 'Red', 'Red': '255', 'Green': '0', 'Blue': '0'}, {'ID': '4', 'Shade': 'Green', 'Red': '0', 'Green': '255', 'Blue': '0'}, {'ID': '5', 'Shade': 'Blue', 'Red': '0', 'Green': '0', 'Blue': '255'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: An attempt without using `json`:

```
def createFile(allColours):
    with open("colours","w") as colours_file:
        for colour in allColours:
            colours_file.write(str(colour))
            colours_file.write('\n')
    colours_file.close()
    output()

def output():
    outputQuestion = input("Would you like the to see the output of the data for colours?(Y/N) \n")
    if outputQuestion.lower() == "y":
    with open("colours","r") as colours_file:
        for colour in colours_file.readlines():
            print(colour, end='\r')
    colours_file.close()
    menu()

def data():
    allColours = []
    allColours.append ({"ID": "1", "Shade": "Black", "Red": "0", "Green": "0", "Blue":"0"})
    allColours.append ({"ID": "2", "Shade": "White", "Red": "255", "Green": "255", "Blue":"255"})
    allColours.append ({"ID": "3", "Shade": "Red", "Red": "255", "Green": "0", "Blue":"0"})
    allColours.append ({"ID": "4", "Shade": "Green", "Red": "0", "Green": "255", "Blue":"0"})
    allColours.append ({"ID": "5", "Shade": "Blue", "Red": "0", "Green": "0", "Blue":"255"})
    createFile(allColours)

def menu():
    colours_file = open("colours","r")
    whatColour = input("What colour would you like to be looked up?\n")
    for colour in colours_file.readlines():
        if whatColour in colour.partition("\'Shade\': ")[2]:
            print(colour)

data()
```

The only part that may unfamiliar or might seem clunky is using [str.partition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) to find the color matching the user's input.

Comment: Is there anyway in which you can do this without Json, something I am very unfamiliar with?

Comment: Sure, thanks for your feedback. I edited answer and gave it a try, if you're unfamiliar with any part, let me know and I can try other ways.

Comment: Thank you very much! Much appreciated.